# Ansible execute a task after a conditional

Tags: windows, automation, ansible, yaml

I would like to create a Ansible playbook to install and to check a java version of a windows server.
For now I have this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Check if java is installed
      win_command: java -version
      register: java_result
      assert:
        that: 
          - java_result is failed
      fail_msg: "Failed - Java is not installed"
           
    - name: Install Java
      win_chocolatey:
        name: "{{ jdk_package }}"
        state: present
        version: "{{ java_major_version }}.{{ java_minor_version }}"
        when: java_version.stdout | version_compare(, '<')

    - name: Set Java_home
      win_environment:
        state: present
        name: JAVA_HOME
        value: 'c:\program files\java\jdk1.{{ java_major_version }}_{{ java_minor_version }}'
        level: machine

    - name: Add Java to path
      win_path:
        elements:
          - 'c:\program files\java\jdk{{ java_major_version }}_{{ java_minor_version }}\bin'
```

I'm not able to test what I did that's why I come to ask for help.
In the first task, where I check to java version, I want to add three scenarios:

- one where java isn't install, returns error and execute the playbook for another server
- one where java isn't updated, perform the following tasks
- one where it's all ok, execute the playbook for another server

Is it possible to create like a if, else if conditions in Ansible? I would be grateful with an example or explanation

Comment: *I'm not able to test what I did that's why I come to ask for help* what does that mean? You don't have a Windows machine against which to try the playbook?

Comment: It's a production machine

Comment: Are you expecting someone on SO to validate your code against a development environment for you ? There are very little chances this will happen. If you are creating playbooks targeting windows, you need a windows machine your can play with while developing. One easy solution is to install a VM in your favorite virtualization platform on your own dev machine for this purpose.